# Magento 2 - How to return custom json response from API

Tags: magento2, api, response

I'm working with Magento 2 API and I'm really struggled with response of it

How can I return some kind of response like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "message": "Request processed successfully.",
    "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "email": "us@test.com",
        "first_name": "user1",
        "last_name": "user01"
    }
}
```

It's simple with other framework like Laravel or Express. But it seems really hard to achieve this with Magento 2 API.

Anyone has idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Give you a reference first, you can edit the format as you like: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/magento-2-sending-a-custom-header-response-from-a-controller?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. But did you try this? I tried, at the moment, this interface has only one method left, it is sendResponse. And it seems not work as we expected

Comment: I didn't try as I don't need to do so, just a reference for you.

Comment: have u found any solution for this in magento2?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa: No, I didn't find the kind of solution I needed. And I had to use response format that Magento team force us to use :)

Answer (score -2):

First you need to define the interface/class of the result type.
The interface will look like this.

```
namespace Vnecoms\SampleAPI\Api;

interface Result
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStatus();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getError();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage();

    /**
     * @return \Vnecoms\SampleAPI\Api\ResultData
     */
    public function getData();
}
```

Next is the ResultData interface

```
namespace Vnecoms\SampleAPI\Api;

interface ResultData
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName();
}
```

Now in your API just return an object of \Vnecoms\SampleAPI\Api\Result

Comment: how to return it?

Comment: I write down the interface only. You will need to define your own class follows the interface above.

Comment: @Hungvt, Is it possible to build that data interface without a getter method for every field? (What can you do when you have, for example, 200 fields? or dynamic number of fields?)

Comment: This is a terrible answer. This doesn't explain anything other than how to create an interface for a few necessary fields.