# Magento2 : Service Contracts response headers

Tags: magento2

If I implement a **custom API** using a **Magento2 service contract**, how can I set the **response headers** of the API calls from inside the service implementation?

EDIT: I am looking for a solution for the scenario that my service implementation is a standard model class and **not a controller**, for example:

```
<route url="/V1/vendor/modulename/my_custom_endpoint" method="POST">
    <service class="Vendor\ModuleName\Api\ServiceInterface" method="my_custom_endpoint"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

and

```
<preference for="Vendor\ModuleName\Api\ServiceInterface" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Service" />
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/magento-2-sending-a-custom-header-response-from-a-controller

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Sorry but I am not asking for a REST API implementation, I am looking for a Service Contract Web API implementation. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you looking for your own status code in response headers?

Answer (score 1):

Choose from available implementations of `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface`.
The most suitable for custom REST API (assuming it operates with JSON) seems to be `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json`. However, if you need something even more custom, consider `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw`.

Working sample:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller;

/**
 * Demo of authorization error for custom REST API
 */
class RestAuthorizationDemo extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory */
    protected $jsonResultFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $result */
        $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
        /** You may introduce your own constants for this custom REST API */
        $result->setHttpResponseCode(\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        $result->setData(['error_message' => __('What are you doing here?')]);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not asking for a REST API implementation, I am looking for a Service Contract Web API implementation. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no proper way to do this yet in Magento 2 Service contract.
So something like this would suffice.

```
header('Content-Type: ' . [content type]);
print [data];
exit();
```

This is how we do it in our project at the moment.

If you've found a solution for this, it would be great if you can share it too.